# Tabularx: columns do not adapt to width

Tags: tables, tabularx, textwidth

I have the following table, written with `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[section]{placeins}


\usepackage{libertinus} %font
\usepackage{libertinust1math} %mathfont
\usepackage{microtype} %improves general typographic
\usepackage{pifont} %allow special symbol like square or circle with shadows
\usepackage{bbding} %adds more symbols
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb} %allows to scale/stretch and shift objects
%\usepackage{gensymb} %Generic symbols for both text and math mode
\usepackage{cancel} %Place lines through maths formulae


\usepackage{titlesec} %allows different title styles


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt} %This command increments column spacing in tables


  
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Performance Using Hard Decision Detection}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{lXXXXXXX}
    \hline\hline 
    Audio Name&\multicolumn{7}{c}{Sum of Extracted Bits} \\
    \hline 
    Police & 5 & -1 & 5& 5& -7& -5& 3\\ 
    Midnight & 7 & -3 & 5& 3& -1& -3& 5\\
    News & 9 & -3 & 7& 9& -5& -1& 9\\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:hresult}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output I get:

[image]

How is possible to get a code which auto-adjust columns width based on `0.8\textwidth` option I set in `tabularx`?
As you can see, the numerical values come out of the table, exceeding margins, among other things. Moreover pointless extra space between columns is added.
Is there anyone who knows how to solve it?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the output shown in your screenshot when I compile your code. Indeed, the output I get is exactly what one would expect it to be. A closer examination of your screenshot reveals that you must have been using additional commands to generate, e.g., to select a non-default font. Please tell us more about your computing setup and the TeX distribution you employ.

Comment: Thank you @Mico, I'm going to update the MWE. I'll write the whole preamble, just in case I forget something. I'm using the latest version of TeXLive.

Comment: shorten the preamble, it should only contain the necessary stuff. Remove package one by one and test if the problem is still there.

Comment: I've found the error, I accidentally copied a part of another code which was: `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}`.

Comment: @Catarella - Indeed, executing `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}` has a drastic effect. However, it's still not enough to generate your screenshot, as the `X` columns should and will permit automatic line-wrapping.

Comment: Since the contents in your columns are rather short and you don't need linebreaks inside of your columns, a simple `tabular*` combined with `\extracolsep{\fill}}` would be sufficient.

Comment: There is  no reason to use tabularx here, tabularx is about _line breaking_ in table cells. You coudl use `tabular*` but forcing the columns apart surves no purpose and makes the table harder to read, so I'd use `tabular` (even though I wrote `tabularx`)

Answer (score 1):

What about one of the following two approaches?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}  
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Performance Using Hard Decision Detection}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lS[table-format=1] S[table-format=-1] *{2}{S[table-format=1]} *{2}{S[table-format=-1]} S[table-format=1]}
    \toprule 
    Audio Name&\multicolumn{7}{c}{Sum of Extracted Bits} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-8} 
    Police & 5 & -1 & 5& 5& -7& -5& 3\\ 
    Midnight & 7 & -3 & 5& 3& -1& -3& 5\\
    News & 9 & -3 & 7& 9& -5& -1& 9\\ 
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular*}
    \label{tab:hresult}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Performance Using Hard Decision Detection}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=1] S[table-format=-1] *{2}{S[table-format=1]} *{2}{S[table-format=-1]} S[table-format=1]}
    \toprule 
    Audio Name&\multicolumn{7}{c}{Sum of Extracted Bits} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-8} 
    Police & 5 & -1 & 5& 5& -7& -5& 3\\ 
    Midnight & 7 & -3 & 5& 3& -1& -3& 5\\
    News & 9 & -3 & 7& 9& -5& -1& 9\\ 
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:hresult}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```